# Создать iframe в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, iframe, плагин

Нужно создать пустую страницу где-то в папках wordpress, чтобы можно было подключить ее через iframe в одном из плагинов. Куда лучше ее поместить, и есть ли какие-то преграды/возможные баги?

Comment: Точно нужна дыра в виде ифрейма? Почему нельзя сделать нормально? Ида "где-то в папках ядра" ничего не создаётся.

Comment: @SeVlad а как иначе если блок поддерживает только html?

Comment: Стоит спросить то, что надо решить, а не придумывать черезанусные решения https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy/710#710

Comment: @SeVlad отлично, как тогда вставить код вместе с js/php в блок который поддерживает только html,

Comment: Спросить *другим вопросом*, внятно описав что откуда и куда.